# jQuery if condition not working on certain input numbers

Tags: jquery

my jQuery if condition does not work like how it should. Everything works good but not on input number "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9". Below is the code. Wonder what went wrong.

```
$(function(){
        $('input').blur(function(){
            var LowerLimit = 10;
            var UpperLimit = 70;
            var CurrVal = $(this).val();
            if (CurrVal<LowerLimit) {
                $(this).val(LowerLimit);
            }
            if (CurrVal>UpperLimit) {
                $(this).val(UpperLimit );
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Parse your input to `int` and try again

Comment: Or change your input type `text` to `number` in HTML codes.

Comment: You should parseInt() our input value of use type="number" in your input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping into `parseInt()` like this

```
var CurrVal = parseInt($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

See your desired output

```js
$(function(){
        $('input').blur(function(){
            var LowerLimit = 10;
            var UpperLimit = 70;
            var CurrVal = $(this).val();
            if (CurrVal<LowerLimit) {
                $(this).val(LowerLimit);
            }
            if (CurrVal>UpperLimit) {
                $(this).val(UpperLimit );
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" />
```

Comment: What if OP wants `input type="text"` only.

Comment: then use  `parseInt($(input).val())`